# NLTK `shortest_path_distance` vs path through `LCS`

Tags: nltk, wordnet

The [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html) interface to WordNet uses only hypernyms in determining the shortest path (`shortest_path_length`).

Wouldn't this result in the length of the path through the `least_common_subsumer` in every case?  I suspect this is a great estimation of shortest path, but is there an alternative implementation that finds the true shortest path?

Comment: How else would you go about looking for `shortest_path_length` other than looking for nearest hypernym?

Comment: Consider the case where two synsets share a common `hyponym` as well.